# Set controller properties from object passed to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller with a function `init()`.
The property passed to `init()` is a object. Like this:

```
init({
  a: "A",
  b: "B"
});
```

How can I bind those values of the object to my controller?
I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
this.init = function(params){
    angular.forEach(params, function (value, key) {
        this[key] = value;
    });
}
```

What I want is when `init()` is done the controller will have the local variables

`this.a = "A"; 
this.b = "B";`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `this` inside callback function. So all you need to do is,

```
var self = this.
this.init = function(params){
    angular.forEach(params, function (value, key) {
        self[key] = value;
    });
}
```